# Cannot access MySQL database with ruby gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nitrousio

I am currently developing in ruby on rails. I am using a web online service from the page Nitrous.io. It provides a text editor and a command line with all rails gems and programs you might need.

I want to use the mysql gem that is already installed, but when I run "mysql"  it fires up the error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Both which `mysql` and `mysql --version` tell me, there *is* a mysql installed but I can't access it.

How can I access my database via the ruby gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your database may be on a different server than the Rails application. If that is the case, Rails won't be able to connect via /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, but needs a network connection to that server. Check your database server credentials against `config/database.yml`.